# Easier way to check if else statements of 3 variables with 7 statements

Tags: python, if-statement, logic

Is there a simple way to test 2 variables with 3 conditions or 3 variables with  7 conditions and so on?

```
def checkXYZ():
    if x==1 and y==0 and z==0:
        doX()
    elif x==0 and y==1 and z==0:
        doY()
    elif x==0 and y==0 and z==1:
        doZ()

    elif x==1 and y==1 and z==0:
        doXY()
    elif x==0 and y==1 and z==1:
        doYZ()
    elif x==1 and y==0 and z==1:
        doXZ()

    elif x==1 and y==1 and z==1:
        doXYZ()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question specific answer, but you can implement `checkXYZ()` function as below:

```py
def checkXYZ():
    if x==1:
        print("x", end='')
    if y==1:
        print('y', end='')
    if z==1:
        print('z', end='')
    print()  # new line

x = 1
y = 0
z = 1
checkXYZ()
```

> xz

`end` parameter given to the `print()` function specifies the last character at the end of your string. By default, `end='\n'`, but you can set it to `''` to avoid putting newlines. 

Alternative solution, inspired by @Sujay and @Yu-Sheng Li

```py
a = b = y = z = 1
c = x = 0
variables = [a,b,c,x,y,z]
strs = "abcxyz"
print(''.join(s for var, s in zip(variables, strs) if var))
```

> abyz

To implement methods:

```py
def doA():
    pass
def doB():
    pass
def doC():
    pass
def doAB():
    pass
def doAC():
    print("AC")
def doBC():
    pass
def doABC():
    pass
    
dict_ = {'a' : doA, 'b': doB, 'c': doC, 'ab': doAB, 'ac': doAC, 'bc': doBC, 'abc': doABC}
variables = [a,b,c]
strs = "abc"
b = 0
a = c = 1
dict_[''.join(s for var, s in zip(variables, strs) if var)]()
```

> AC

Comment: what if it isn't a print statement but its to call another function?

Comment: @Mehteva I was just asking out of curiosity, because if there were more variables, then we would have to have more if statements and was checking if there was a way to shorten it (for example 4 variables, will have 15 statements)

Comment: I added one way to do it, you can put functions into ```dict```.

Comment: I think this does not work as doAC() already printed and returned None in the creation of `dict_`. You need `dict_ = {'a': doA, ...}` and in the end `dict_[...]()`

Comment: You are right, corrected. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

EDITED: to run methods (though `exec` is not recommended)

```
def check_vars(variables, strs, prefix="do"):
    method = prefix + "".join(s for var, s in zip(variables, strs) if var)
    exec(f"{method}()")

# in your case
check_vars([x, y, z], "XYZ")
```

General solution:

```
def check_vars(variables, strs):
    ans = ""
    for var, s in zip(variables, strs):
        if var:
            ans += s
    print(ans)

# in your case
check_vars([x, y, z], "xyz")
```

Comment: what if it isn't a print statement but its to call another function?

Comment: This can be shortened as `''.join(s for var, s in zip(vars, strs) if var)`. Concatenation of strings is slower than the above one

Comment: @Sujay Nice, I was thinking about that as well

Comment: @swaziland In that case I think you need to pass another dict mapping from (1, 1, 0) to doXY, for example.

Comment: @swaziland updated, without the need to provide mapping, but has assumption on the names of the methods